# Which software is suitable to project a video on a virtual hollow sphere?

Tags: windows, open-source, video, 3d

Actioncams have a fisheye. Therefore recorded videos are intentionally distorted. In this distortion, a range of view is encoded, by projecting it on a sphere and putting a camera in the middle, you get a horizontal field of view of about 175°.

Which software framework (xna, unity, ...) in the free version is best suited to create a program that offers to load a video file, projects this video file on a sphere and lets the user view it with his mouse or head tracker. How could you go about creating it in the software mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

You could almost certainly use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to do this by inverting the values used for k1 and k2 the [lens correction filter](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lenscorrection) so as to take an undistorted input and produce a fisheye output.

- Free
- Open-source
- Cross platform – *most major platforms are supported*

Alternatively you could use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to do the job.

Comment: "as to take an undistorted input and produce a fish-eye output." it is about the other way round.

Comment: @Zurechtweiser - if you take a movie that was not filmed through a fisheye and apply the opposite correction to that which would have been needed to generate it from a fisheye format film then it should produce the fisheye.  I read the question as I have a normal film and I need a fisheye.